# Redirect domain to the specified ip:port when accessing domain with browser

Tags: domain, domain-name-system

How to redirect domain to the ip with specified port instead of port 80 when accessing with browser?

For example, accessing example.com in browser will pointed to 127.0.0.1:33333

Comment: Where do you want to do the redirect? Do you control the webserver for the domain in question?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want a 'Reverse Proxy'.

You can look at [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).

Or if you are looking for an easy personal option, look at [CaddyServer](https://caddyserver.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can redirect the browser.

Something like this in the head section of your HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://127.0.0.1:33333'" />
```

You could do it with Javascript:

```
window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:33333";
```

This site gives a great explanation of redirecting.  I have it bookmarked...

[https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/#:~:text=A%20redirect%20is%20when%20a,%2Fpage%2Db%E2%80%9D%20instead](https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/#:%7E:text=A%20redirect%20is%20when%20a,%2Fpage%2Db%E2%80%9D%20instead).

hth,

David

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).